# How to get the top most type of an instance variable?

Tags: c#, validation, postsharp, system.reflection

Say I have an instance variable that is declared to be a given base class. I want to find what the original, upper-most type that object actually is instead of the base class. How do I do this?

I have a validation attribute a la PostSharp so the reflection hit is at compile-time and is therefore moot thanks to the `CompileTimeValidation` method. I'm simply at a loss of how I'd do this. Doing an `IsSubclassOf` scan isn't helpful as I'd get multiple false positives.

To give context, I have a base `Entity` type. I derive from this type all over defining all kinds of `Entity` types. I decorate these types, including the base `Entity`, with a policy attribute. The PostSharp aspect verifies at compile-time certain policy constraints. I would like to be able to only decorate the base `Entity` type with the aspect validation so that `Entity` and all its derived types will be validated. I can see the validation already happen. However, it's handled as an `Entity` and not `DerivedEntity`. In order to evaluate the policy on `DerviedEntity`, I need to decorate that class specifically. I would like to not do this if possible and only decorate `Entity`.

Essentially, I want to centralize my validation on the base class as the validation schema is the same for all derived classes. However, the values in the derived classes can change and I need to do some bounds checking.

Edit: Let's add some code.

```
[EnforceMaxLifetimePolicy]
[LifetimePolicy]
public class Entity<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T Object { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan EntityLifetime
    {
        get
        {
            var lifetimePolicy =
                Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(), typeof(LifetimePolicyAttribute)) as LifetimePolicyAttribute;

            return new TimeSpan(lifetimePolicy.Hours, lifetimePolicy.Minutes, 0);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal class LifetimePolicyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public readonly short Hours;
    public readonly short Minutes;

    public LifetimePolicyAttribute(short hours, short minutes)
    {
        Hours = hours;
        Minutes = minutes;
    }

    public LifetimePolicyAttribute()
    {
        Minutes = 1;
    }
}

[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
internal class EnforceMaxLifetimePolicyAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
    {
        var type = method.GetType();

        var lifetimePolicy = GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(LifetimePolicyAttribute)) as LifetimePolicyAttribute;

        if (lifetimePolicy != null && lifetimePolicy.Hours + lifetimePolicy.Minutes / 60 > 24)
        {
            throw new InvalidAnnotationException($"Lifetimes can not exceed 24 hours. The lifetime on {type.FullName} is invalid.");
        }

        return true;
    }
}

[LifetimePolicy(hours: 24, minutes: 0)]
internal class ShoppingCartEntity : Entity<ShoppingCart>
{
}
```

As you can see, ShoppingCartEntity does not have the `[EnforceMaxLifetimePolicy]` on it. It's on the base class `Entity`. However, I still want the Enforce attribute entity to also apply to derived types which is why I leave the `Inherited` flag to its default (true).

Comment: Would `obj.GetType()` work for you?

Comment: I suppose that your upper-most type is always `object` :)

Comment: @AndreiM Unfortunately not. If I do that, I only ever evaluate the policy attribute on the base `Entity` and don't get the attribute on the appropriate child type.

Comment: @Bigsby you know you can always check `obj is Entity` or any other type you need.

Comment: Can you show some code? I have a hard time understanding the actual problem.

Comment: Please post code so we can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PatrickHofman Added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, PostSharp obviates this need. It supports automatic application to derived types via Multicasting. So, the lifetime attribute looks like so:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
internal class EnforceMaxLifetimePolicyAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
    {
        var type = method.DeclaringType;

        var lifetimePolicy = GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(LifetimePolicyAttribute)) as LifetimePolicyAttribute;

        if (lifetimePolicy.Hours + lifetimePolicy.Minutes / 60 > 24)
        {
            throw new InvalidAnnotationException($"Lifetimes can not exceed 24 hours. The lifetime on {type.FullName} is invalid.");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The `[MulticastAttributeUsage(Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]` line will have PostSharp automatically apply it to the `ShoppingCartEntity` and others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your problem but you can always find out:

### 1. Object actual type (use obj.GetType()):

```
if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Entity)) { ... }
```

### 2. If object is derived from some type (use "is" operator):

```
if (obj is Entity) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over every base class until you hit rock bottom. Stop on the first occasion of the attribute you are looking for:

```
var type = method.GetType();

do
{
    var lifetimePolicy = GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(LifetimePolicyAttribute)) as LifetimePolicyAttribute;
    if (lifetimePolicy != null)
    {
        // process
        break; // out of the do...while
    }
} while ((type = type.BaseType) != null);
```